# in macbook, python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I got a problem that [Errno 2] No such file or directory. I have never seen before in window visual studio.

below is my code which is problem occur

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a selenium Firefox web driver.